# Setting the entity object to request object manually before Binding the request in symfony2

Tags: symfony, request, bind

I have a form which has a collection for manager which is an autocomplete textfeild.

[image]

While the form binds, It throws the error as it expects manager object. But the manager text field contains only simple text.

```
  if ($request->getMethod() === 'POST') {

                $Form->bindRequest($request);


                }
```

So i manually queried to access the manager object based on the manager name, but how to set it to the `$request` object before binding `request`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Using Data Transformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) cookbook entry — it covers exactly what you want.